# iphone multiple image url loading in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display or load multiple images from a server and load it in tableview or image view  ...if a single url with image is coming then imageview or tableview loads the image, but more that one image is coming then it did not load the multiple images,

my code is

```
NSString *urlVal = @"http://at.azinova.info/green4care/iphone/viewImage.php?id=";

NSString *urlVal1 = [urlVal stringByAppendingString:selectedCountryw];

NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlVal1];


NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

resultString=[resultString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

NSArray *profileedit = [resultString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#***#"];
lbl.text = resultString;
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lbl.text]]];
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ALERT" message:resultString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert1 show];

[alert1 release];
```

selectedCountryw is just an id

resultstring is the url from the server ,it may be one image or more than one image

Comment: can you clean up the code? I dont see you making more than one request (web loadrequest) ?

Comment: resultstring holds the image url ,,,,how to make more than one request??

Comment: i just want to load multiple images from url and load it in tableview or imageview,,,,i tried lot ,,but unsuccessfull...please help me.

Comment: Maybe you don't get the whole programming thing, what's your backup?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a function that takes a parameter for selectedCountryw
2. The function returns a UIImage
3. Call the function every time you need an image, the function makes the request and creates the image
4. Set the image in the UITableView

Once you've gotten this far, let us know where you are and we'll jump right in and help.

```
-(UIImage*)getImage:(NSString*)country
{

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://at.azinova.info/green4care/iphone/viewImage.php?id=%@", country];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
    NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImage]]] retain];
    return image;
}
```

Better yet..Do a search on SO or Google for Lazy TableView Loading. That'll get you started.

Edited to provide additional information:

I'll leave it up to you to optimize.

Comment: -(UIImage*)getImage:(NSString*)country
{
what code did i enter here?
}

Comment: i saw laziy tableview loading,,but i didnt understand,it too complicated to understand me ,becz i am a fresher to this field,it have lotes of .h and.m files,,i just want loading images from url to a tableview..

Comment: Code posted above works just fine for me. If you're having problems with some other aspect. Accept this answer and post new question with errors and code.

Comment: but where is resultstring in the above code?sir resultstring is my imageurl from the server,,so where did i declare resultstring

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of much help with this, since I have no idea what you are doing. You're better off accepting this answer and asking another question. Please do this to receive immediate help.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is the SDwebimage which is very simple to use and is the best library to do this kind of stuff here's the [link](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/tag/sdwebimage/) to that